# How to display child posts of a given post with pagination?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am newbie for wordpress. Can anyone help me to display a list of posts under given parent post. I need to manage pagination for those child posts. I have used this code.

```
 $all_pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_title');
foreach($all_pages as $pages)
           {
                     // here goes display of the post info
                   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links). Use it to create the pagination HTML, along with a bit of PHP logic to create the values for the `limit` and `offset` variables you can pass into `get_pages()`.